# in linux how to stop or suspend or hangup a job without using fg command or ctrl+z?

Tags: linux, command-line, job-control

i am new on linux but i have an assignment and it requires to stop and suspend and hangup certain jobs without using the fg or ctrl+z commands like this picture and what does the dot after the number represent and what does the & symbol represent in the third job[image: press to see picture]

Comment: Can't tell you what these dots and symbols mean. We don't have the context for that image, only you do. To me, this looks either very nonsensical, or has to be defined elsewhere in your learning material, which we don't have.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i need to make a txt file and write this script inside it while

Comment: To add something, you should have edited [your first question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704122/108618). Your two question are almost duplicates, none shows research effort.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes i know i should have edited it but i have researched a lot and I got no questions on the first question that's why I have asked another one and searched every where for an answer and I cannot find

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. Full stop.

Comment: @A.B  No, because that is the duplicate question asked by the OP earlier today.

Comment: What OS distro and shell versions are you assumed to be using for this work? I am unable to reproduce this list in either ksh93u+, or Bash 4.4.20 (GKIT). Both of them remove a job *immediately* with HUP or KILL, so it never appears in the jobs list as shown in your graphic. ksh also lists the job name as `<command unknown>`, although Bash manages to output the script name.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I wasn't the one to initially propose duplicate, but SE made it look this way. Anyway, one shouldn't encourage to ask again the same question because it got no answer. Maybe cross-posted? Not either it's same-posted...

Answer (score 1):

The graphic shown is the output from a `jobs` command (transcribed for printing, because that font cannot be from an actual terminal).

Assume you have a script called `forever` (which needs an infinite loop, hopefully with an embedded `sleep 10` to avoid 100% CPU usage).

Then imagine you start six jobs in your shell which all run `forever`, and send them various signals from a *different* shell window. You can only have one foreground command at once, so you need to hangup job 1 before you can start job 2, etc.

All the job states relate to different SIG codes that you send (with `kill`) to the process numbers. You need to discover the process numbers, because the job numbers only relate to the first shell, and you need to send signals from the second shell. Frequent use of `pstree $PPID` might be helpful.

Job 3 is in background, and and the other five have been inhibited externally, so there is no foreground task, and you get your shell prompt back again. That's where you can issue the `jobs` command, and get the output.

The `&` shows job 3 was started in background. The `-` `.` `+` are job status information output by the shell.

Edit: I cannot make this work in Bash. I think this may be related to the way Bash aggressively collects process termination status before you ask for it. I will try another shell later.